# What's the difference between an API like /api?some=param or /api/?some=param

Tags: http, url

I just saw this URL:

```
https://browser.pipe.aria.microsoft.com/Collector/3.0/?qsp=true&content-type=application...
```

But I've also seen URLs like this before:

```
http://some.website.com/api/verb?param=1&param=2...
```

What's the difference between those? Just cosmetic?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the technology used (WEB api, MVC api, ...), and how the developper coded, it's certainly not the same code behind

Answer (score 0):

*"What's the difference between those? Just cosmetic?"*

Semantically, they indicate 2 different resources, and it's NOT cosmetic.

`/api?some=param` indicates resource `/api`, while `/api/?some=param` indicates resource group `/api/`. When request to resource group `/api/` is received, web server may decide to return:

- Default resource of the resource group, such as `/api/index.html` or `/api/index.jsp`.
- Deny the request and return error. [requestb.in](https://requestb.in) uses this policy. If a URL endpoint is created (e.g. https://requestb.in/1hl8k4u1), `GET https://requestb.in/1hl8k4u1` would return `ok`, but `GET https://requestb.in/1hl8k4u1/` would return `404 Not Found`.
- Take the resource group as single resource entity, i.e. take `/api/` as `/api`. [Express.js](http://expressjs.com/) uses this policy. In Express.js, `router.get('/api/', ...)` and `router.get('/api', ...)` is the same thing.